# Are questions asking for a security audit on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Given TheDAO hack, security has become more of a focus for smart contracts.  Are questions that request for an audit or analysis of smart contracts for vulnerabilities and ways to improve, on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

In general I feel these questions are hardly on-topic or too broad for our site. They do not attempt to question a certain problem the user faces with her code but rather generating a general feedback loop which could lead to open discussions.

However, it might be worth to highlight and recommend the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

> **Code Review** is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The community decided to close such a question as off-topic:
[Please help auditing my first contract!](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8179/please-help-auditing-my-first-contract)

Other similar questions may have to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis, for example some of them may be off-topic due to being too broad, or primarily opinion-based.